# Compare layers of two dimensional array simultaneously

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project for an Algorithms class in Java, and I am stuck with this problem I cannot figure out.

I have a two dimensional array of size [m][n], where m and n can fluctuate depending on input. I want to condense the values into a single dimension array based on which value is the lowest out of any vertical column in the two dimensional array. Here are two samples of the array.

Sample 1 input:

```
3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0 
0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0
```

Sample 1 output:

```
0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0
```

Sample 2 input:

```
0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0 
2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0 
1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0 
1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0 
2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0
```

Sample 2 output:

```
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
```

And this is the logic I want to sort is this:

```
loop through the 2-d array
at every vertical index, compare all values within the vertical index,
output lowest value to single dimensional array
```

I believe this is a somewhat simple problem, but I cannot wrap my head around how to do this properly. Thank you for any advice you can provide!

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that for input[m][n] m would be your rows and n would be your columns, so you have to traverse column wise to get the lowest value in that column:

```
int[] output = new int[n];
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   output[n] = input[0][n];
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   for(k = 0; k < m; k++)
      if(output[n] > input[m][n])
          output[n] = input[m][n];
```

Comment: `if(output[n] > input[m][n])` this condition always fails here, `output[n]` always zero and lesser value than values in 2-d array. I think first loop need to be like `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)   output[n] = input[m][0];`

Comment: `output[n] = input[0][n];` I think its `output[n] = input[n][0];`

Comment: No it should be output[n] = input[0][n], because this is the initialization step of the output so you have to get each column of first row of the input, remember in your array matrix input[m][n], m isyour rows and n is your columns

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got confused with `input[m][n]` & `input[n][m]`